# structures in arrays

Tags: iphone

I want to add a structure to arrays. The following is my structure

struct Nodes {

```
NSInteger nodeGridNumber;
Boolean visited;
struct Nodes *nextNode;
```

};

Can any one with help with this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion for you would be to use class instead of struct:

```
@interface Nodes : NSObject{

  NSInteger nodeGridNumber;
  Boolean visited;
  struct Nodes *nextNode;

};
```

Then you could add it to NSMutableArray.
And of course, import class header file, where you need to use this class.

Answer (score 1):

Use :
Nodes *node = [Nodes alloc]; 
NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[arr addObject:node];

Comment: I am getting error at this line Nodes *node = [Nodes alloc]; say undefined symbols Nodes and node. I tried using type def typedef struct Nodes NodeStruct; and rewritten the code this way. NodeStruct *node;// = [NodeStruct alloc];
 NSMutableArray *arr =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [arr addObject:node];
Then I am getting the error in the last line sayingpassing argument of incompatable type.